# How to get products according to User in Django?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, django-templates

I have relation between `Customer` and `Products`, and `customer_id` is saving in `Product` model table, but I want to display products on my view page according to `customer`, suppose if a customer logged in using his details then he can see only his products, but currently he can see all products. Please let me know How I can do it.

Here is my `models.py` file...

```
class Customer(models.Model):
    name=models.CharField(default=None)
    user=models.OneToOneField(User, related_name='userwithCustomer', on_delete=models.CASCADE)

class Product(models.Model):
    name=models.CharField(default=None)
    customer=models.Foreignkey(Customer, related_name='customer_product', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

here is my `views.py` file...

```
def display_data(request):
    test_display = Product.objects.all()
    context = {
        'test_display': test_display
    }
    return render(request, 'page.html', context)
```

here is my `page.html` file...here i am trying to display products according to loggedin customer..

```
<p>{{test_display.count}}</p>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're sure that your user is logged in (i.e. session authenticated) you can change your queryset from `test_display = Product.objects.all()` to `test_display = Product.objects.filter(customer=request.user)`. If you want to have login constraint on your view you can use `login_required` decorator on your view:

```
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required

@login_required
def display_data(request):
    test_display = Product.objects.filter(customer=request.user)
    context = {
        'test_display': test_display
    }
    return render(request, 'page.html', context)
```

Comment: Actually I want to count the total number of products of this customer in in `product` table

Comment: @Amit use Product.objects.filter(customer=request.user).len()

Comment: Well this is a filtered queryset based on customer... it is all related to your requirements... such as iterating or counting... like `<p>{{test_display.count}}</p>` for counting your results.

Comment: it's displaying `'QuerySet' object has no attribute 'len'`, if I am using this `Product.objects.filter(customer=request.user.id).len()`

Comment: I mentioned it in last comment... you should use something like `Product.objects.filter(customer_id=request.user.id).count()` for counting results.

Comment: it's counting me `0` results but in database there are `4` products in `product` table with this `customer_id`

Comment: Ohh Sorry, I have `OneToOneField` relation of `User` with 'Customer`,Please check my updated question and please guide me Now, How i can Count the products according to `customer_id`

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are using the product instead of customer, which as a result will display all products instead of the ones solely owned by said user. Replace this line of code:

```
Product.objects.all()
```

with:

```
request.user.customer_product.all()
```

and it should only show the logged in user's items. For the display, you have to make a for loop to show the details of each item like so:

```
<ul>
{% for test in test_display %}
<li>{{test.name}}:${{test.price}}</li>
{% endfor %}
</ul>
```